# How to use Inline align*

Tags: beamer, align

In beamer slides, I want to save space so I want to place the `align*` environment next to the text as in the following illustration:

[image: Inline align* environment]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array`.  The `[t]` option indicates that the array should be top-aligned.  The `{}` before the `=` ensure that the spacing around the `=` is correct.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item One has $\begin{array}[t]{@{}r@{}l@{}} 
           A &{}= \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i\,x^i\\
             &{}= \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i\,x^i
         \end{array}$
  \end{itemize} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

P.S. Instead of adding `@{}`, another option is to define `\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}`.

Answer (score 14):

I would recommend the `aligned` environment instead of `align*` for this case, using `[t]` for the alignment as in the `array` example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item One has
  $\begin{aligned}[t]
    A &= \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i x^i\\
      &= \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i x^i
  \end{aligned}$
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Using `aligned` has a more convenient input syntax that works just like `align` and friends, and has better spacing between lines than the `array` method, with no need for manual spacing tweaks.

[image]

Comment: This is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use this, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328968/36296 is a much cleaner solution.

If you want to keep the `align*` for some reason or another, you can fake being inline by adding a negative space. Depending on font size etc. you will have to adjust the value manually.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item One has
  \vspace*{-1.05cm}
  \begin{align*}
    A &= \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i x^i\\
      &= \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i x^i
  \end{align*}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]